Finding the domain of this function $f(x,y) = \ln(xy+x-y-1)$
$$f(x,y) = \ln(xy+x-y-1)$$
I know that:
$$xy+x-y-1 > 0 $$
I don't know how to graph the domain of this function
I was trying:
$$xy+x-y > 1$$
$$y(x-1)+x>1$$
$$y > \frac{1-x}{x-1}$$
$$y > -1$$
$$y = -1$$
is the domain of this function all of the real values above the line $y= -1$ ?

Try factoring the expression inside the $\ln$.

@JonathanZ the domain is all of the points above $y = -1$ right?

No. You can't divide the inequality by $x-1$, as it might be negative. You should try coming up with a factorization for the entire quantity inside the $\ln$.

@JonathanZ you mean using the properties of the logarithm?

Nope. It's just an algebraic expression. You can factor it with high school algebra. (Yes, it's because that expression has a very special form, and it's not a regular thing that one can factor a polynomial in two variables, but for this one we can, so i think that's what the question expects us to do.)

$$
xy + x - y - 1 > 0 \\
\Rightarrow x(y + 1) - (y + 1) > 0 \\
\Rightarrow (x-1)(y + 1) > 0 \\
\begin{cases}
\begin{cases}
x - 1 > 0 \\
y + 1 > 0
\end{cases} \\
\begin{cases}
x - 1 < 0 \\
y + 1 < 0
\end{cases}
\end{cases} \Rightarrow 
\begin{cases}
\begin{cases}
x > 1 \\ y > -1
\end{cases} \\
\begin{cases}
x < 1 \\ y < -1
\end{cases}
\end{cases}
$$
Hope it helps.

From $(x-1)(y+1)>0$, with words : the domain is made of quadrants  I and III when origin is taken at $(1,-1)$.
